# Rounding number to lowest 35

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve the following, round any number to the lowest 35.

For example:

5 = 0

34 = 0

90 = 70

105 = 105

110 = 105

I'm using the following code right now,

```
$top = (event.pageY-50);
    $top = Math.floor(($top/35))*35;
```

However, when it's 153, it should round it to 140, however it rounds it to 105?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var $top = 153; $top = Math.floor(($top/35))*35;` produces `140` for me.

Comment: `Math.floor(153/35)*35 == 140` in my browser.

Comment: Math.floor(153/35)*35 equals 140 in my console.

Comment: Seems like `$top` is not `153`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function to35(x){return Math.floor(x/35)*35;};
[5,34,35,36,90,100,105,110,153,160].map(to35);

/*
0,0,35,35,70,70,105,105,140,140
*/
```

Am I missing something? The input of 153 produces the correct result of 140.

Comment: Yep you were, my error when deducting the 50, my original code as well as yours is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo

```
$top = (event.pageY-50);
alert( $top - ( $top % 35) );
```

**Check this Snippet**

```js
window.calculate = function (){
    $top = document.getElementById('num').value;
    alert( $top - ( $top % 35) ); 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id='num' value="153" />
<input type="button" id='sub' value="calc" onClick='calculate()' />
```

Explanation:

You have eg 153 if you take this module 35 you get 13 Rest, just substract this from your base number and you got what you want :)

```
153 % 35 = 13
153 - 13 = 140

140/35 = 4
```

and the clostest bottom to 153

Comment: Guess the devoter is just jealous that he didnt had the right answere! But a reason why would be nice.

Comment: I didn't downvote.. Someones gone through all the answers and doing it

Comment: Posting an equivalent version of some code doesn't answer why the code fails to work.

Comment: @Robert so if you have a car and allways drive against a wall its better when I say: `Try to use your brakes befor you hit the wall` instead of `May you just use the street` ? Very unless comment!

Comment: It's common practice to use `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil` or `Math.round` to round down, up or to the closest integer. In fact it's the only use of these functions. I assume `num - num % 1` (which rounds towards zero) is much less common. Now if someone wants to round to multiples of an integer different from `1` it's still common to use the Math functions. Suggesting to use the modulo operator is a great comment but it doesn't qualify as an answer. It's like suggesting to use a different make of car for driving against walls.

Comment: ok, next time if someone has a problem and i only can come up with a solution that not contains ops parts of source... ill wont post ;)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is equivalent to

```
var $top = (event.pageY-50);
$top -=  $top%35;
```

And it will yield 140 when passed 153 as a value